# Running a query with missing variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

This script is selecting data based on optional fields in a HTML form. Although they are optional fields, at least 1 must be entered with the idea being that the more fields entered, the more likely you are to get a single result. For test I have two records with the same first and last name but different ID's and mobile numbers. At the moment when entering a name, 2 fields are given... Correct but when entering a mobile or ID, two results are still displayed.

Ive tried reading into passing missing variables in an SQL query but haven't got very far. Anything blindingly obviously wrong?

Thanks

```
<?php

include "checkmysqlconnect.php";

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$attendid = $_POST['attendid'];
$search = $_POST['search'];

if ($search == "Search") {
if ($firstname == '' AND $lastname == '' AND $attendid == '' AND $mobile == '') {
    header("Location: searchattendform.php?result=1");
        $error = true;
    }

    if($error != true) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `attend` WHERE `firstname` = '".$firstname."' AND `lastname` = '".$lastname."' AND `attendid` = '".$attendid."' AND `mobile` = '".$mobile."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($count > 1) {
while($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "More than one attendee with this name. Entering more details will help narrow down results.";
    echo "<tr><td>".$value['attendid']."</td><td>".$value['wristband']."</td><td>".$value['firstname']."</td><td>".$value['lastname']."</td><td>".$value['telephone']."</td><td>".$value['mobile']."</td><td>".$value['address1']."</td><td>".$value['address2']."</td><td>".$value['town']."</td><td>".$value['postcode']."</td><td>".$value['email']."</td><td>".$value['medical']."</td></tr>";
} } else {
if ($count == 0) {
    header("Location: searchattendform.php?result=2");
} else {
    if ($count == 1) {
        ($value = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
        echo "<tr><td>".$value['attendid']."</td><td>".$value['wristband']."</td><td>".$value['firstname']."</td><td>".$value['lastname']."</td><td>".$value['telephone']."</td><td>".$value['mobile']."</td><td>".$value['address1']."</td><td>".$value['address2']."</td><td>".$value['town']."</td><td>".$value['postcode']."</td><td>".$value['email']."</td><td>".$value['medical']."</td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "The was an issue searching attendees. Please contact SOFia Admin.";
        } }
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated and you are open to sql injection attacks by passing user entered data directly into your query

Comment: Prepared statements and bind placeholders are *not that hard*.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is that your query always checks all the variables:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `attend` WHERE `firstname` = '".$firstname."' AND `lastname` = '".$lastname."' AND `attendid` = '".$attendid."' AND `mobile` = '".$mobile."'";
```

You probably want to break it up, and build it dynamically, something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `attend` WHERE ";

$whereArray = [];
if ($lastName){
    $whereArray[] = "`lastname` = '".$lastname."'";
}
if ($firstname){
    $whereArray[] = "`firstname` = '".$firstname."'";
}

//etc...

$sql .= join(" AND ", $whereArrray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify this to use parametrization, but this should see you in the right direction:

```
include "checkmysqlconnect.php";

((isset($_POST['firstname']) && $_POST['firstname'] != '') ? $firstname = '%'.$_POST['firstname'].'%' : null); //prevents unneeded variables

...

if (!(isset($firstname) or isset($lastname) or isset($attendid) or isset($mobile))) { //checks that at least one variable has been provided

...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `attend` WHERE 1=1"; //returns all; necessary for building the query since you have an unknown number of parameters
(isset($firstname) ? $sql .= " AND `firstname` like '".$firstname."': null); //adds to the query only if the variable exists

...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using some kind of database wrapper class. This will help generate the SQL for you. There are many other reasons why this is a good idea.

There are plenty of MySQL wrappers and most frameworks have one. You could try for example, CodeIgniter, which is very simple framework to install and work with. Then, to create the query you would do something like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
  $this->db->where('firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
}

if(isset($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
  $this->db->where('lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
}

...

$results = $this->db->>get('attend');
foreach($results->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->firstname;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to place var_dump($sql); die(); after the $sql statement and test what that returns.

Comment: $error = true; should be defined before the header redirection.

Comment: $error = true;
header("Location: searchattendform.php?result=1");

Comment: And define the $error = false; after the include statement (include "checkmysqlconnect.php";  )